# Get the last tweet with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to have the last tweet of the user with Tweepy. This is my code :

```
class Bot:
    def __init__(self, keys):
        self._consumer_key = keys[0]
        self._consumer_secret = keys[1]
        self._access_token = keys[2]
        self._access_secret = keys[3]

        try:
            auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(self._consumer_key,
                                       self._consumer_secret)
            auth.set_access_token(self._access_token, self._access_secret)

            self.client = tweepy.API(auth)
            if not self.client.verify_credentials():
                raise tweepy.TweepError
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print('ERROR : connection failed. Check your OAuth keys.')
        else:
            print('Connected as @{}, you can start to tweet !'.format(self.client.me().screen_name))
            self.client_id = self.client.me().id


    def get_last_tweet(self):
        tweet = self.client.user_timeline(id = self.client_id, count = 1)
        print(tweet.text)
        # AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text' .
```

I understand the error, but how can I have the text from a status?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The return value of API.user_timelines, as stated in the [API reference](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline), is a *list* of Status objects.

```
def get_last_tweet(self):
    tweet = self.client.user_timeline(id = self.client_id, count = 1)[0]
    print(tweet.text)
```

Note the additional `[0]` to fetch the first entry.

I'm pretty sure the author of Tweepy happily accepts a pull request with improved documentation ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think I will help for the documentation while I will be good enought with tweepy (maybe a french doc would easier for me). Just one more question, how to get the url from this tweet ? I can make it it's easy (`https://twitter.com/{}/status/{}`.format(tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.id)`) but is there an attribute with the url directly? Thanks again!

Comment: From looking at the code, it should be possible to use [API.get_oembed](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L299). In your case, something like `self.client.get_oembed(id=tweet.id).url`. But it's just a guess, I haven't tested that.