# How to get the last tweets of an account

Tags: python, tweepy

Im working on a script that is looking for the last tweets of a twitter user.

im using tweepy and I know there is this answer which works
[Get the last tweet with tweepy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32022845/get-the-last-tweet-with-tweepy)

however it also prints the replies of a user.
And i would like to have only the actual tweets a person is sending out

```
tweetL = api.user_timeline(screen_name='elonmusk', tweet_mode="extended")
print(tweetL[0].full_text)
```

How can i do this is there a function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an extra parameter to the `user_timeline` function, it's called `exclude_replies`.

Please checkout the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.user_timeline) to know all the posible parameters of that function.

Comment: If your question is answered please mark it as answered.